# Changing one table in EDMX file affect all actions at project. The schema is not valid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, key, edmx

We are using VS2010 and MVC 3.

This project was working fine. With over 40 tables in EDMX Model.  We change a one table over EDMX file and then nothing work.

All actions (related or not with change) gives this error:

> The scheme is not valid. Errors:
>
> The type has no key member. Both RelationshipType as EntityType must
>   have members with BaseType key or key members. The type has no key
>   member. Both RelationshipType as EntityType must have members with
>   BaseType key or key members.
>
> Description:  An unhandled exception when running the current Web
>   request.  Check the stack trace for more information about the error
>   and where it originated in the code.

All tables has a key...

We are restoring a old backup, and working fine... rebuild and then nothing work. !!!

Any idea,  thank you in advance...

For example: (this is a piece of Modelo.designer.cs)

`public ObjectSet Clientes {
    get 
    {
         if ((_Clientes == null))
         {
             _Clientes = base.CreateObjectSet("Clientes"); // ERROR HERE
         }
         return _Clientes;
    }
    }`

Same error for all tables in the Model (EDMX). We are rebuild Model.designer.cs using right mouse menu option "execute custom tool"

We deleted old Model, create a new and... the same error.

Comment: There were two ViewModels under construction and without key!

These classes are a new controllers and the error occurred in all controllers. (the old controllers worked fine)

Answer (score 0):

Change EDMX model and then do update model from database -> refresh -> table

Comment: We didn't want to update the model from the database, because this model had manual modifications it was working fine. but ...
We deleted old Model, create, modify and... the same error.